# how to get 2 email-addresse in property "To" from function sendEmail()

Tags: javascript, arrays

i use script smtp.js.
There is a property "To" in the documentation it says i need to enter an array.

I tried
To: ['receiver1@email.tld', 'receiver2@email.tld'],

That does not work.
I am looking for the right syntax with no luck so far, anyone a hint please?

Regards,
Jan

Answer (score 0):

```
function sendEmail(toemail=[]) {
  Email.send({
    ...
    To: toemail.join(), // it will join array value with ',' and return string
    ...
   }).then().catch();
}
```

An example is of join

```
var emails = ['one@gmail.com','two@gmail.com'];
console.log(emails.join())
```

log will be

```
one@gmail.com,two@gmail.com
```